# Schema? What is it exactly. Why don't we have Create Schema statement, w.r.t Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-schema

I have a  database which has several tables. Now there are N users having access to that database and these tables.

Only difference is that each one has different login id, password but the access rights to tables, privileges all are same. A typical project environment.

So is each user having his own schema, or they are connecting to same schema and they are just users.

When you access a table say something.tables_name here something is User? Schema?

Comment: Read here before asking: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm

Comment: Yes, read it already but it didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Useful information I found out.

Use below to know your schema and user name, should be same.

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') from dual; 
select sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') from dual;
```

You can Know the objects owned by your schema

```
select * from user_objects
```

In my case they are just synonyms to objects(table,views) of some main Schemas which was causing confusion. I was thinking I am just a user, but all objects owned by that user is called Schema you can say I am not an important schema.

```
select * from DBA_objects
```

Above will show all schema objects in the database. Hell lot of.

```
select * from DBA_CATALOG
```

List the name, type, and owner (USER view does not display owner) for all tables, views, synonyms, and sequences in the database.

In my case I am able to access tables since I have many synonyms. So you can say I am a user and have a schema and have access to schema of a main User. Users like me are dropped and added but not main User.

Answer (score 1):

You asked, "When you access a table say something.tables_name here something is User? Schema?

Schema.  It just so happens it's the same as the userId.  From the link from oscar:
"A schema is a collection of logical structures of data, or schema objects. A schema is owned by a database user and has the same name as that user. Each user owns a single schema."

There is a 1-to-1 relationship between user and schema.

However through permissions and grants, a user can be granted accesses to OTHER user's schemas.

Comment: But in my case it's different from my login id. And I can access table directly without using something, but sometimes if it won't work then I had to attach something.  as a prefix and I could access.

Comment: @garg10may - Maybe you're working with global synonyms if you don't use schema prefixes?

Comment: What does return `select sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') from dual;` and `select sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') from dual;` ?

Comment: Ok think I understood it, was looking for answer from a working project perspective. Whenever a new user joins, they own nothing. Just are granted select on each table, views etc. and to the common Schema. In my case if I have access I can do select * from table, otherwise select * from something.table, something being owner of tables.

Comment: @Yammy, yes I could see view definitions have public global synonyms, also in definition I see Grant select on table to tagarg(me)

Comment: @Sylvain, it shows same thing tagarg, can I find objects owned by me?

Comment: When you start getting into what you can see vs what you can't it helps to understand the privileges: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/doc/timesten.1122/e21642/privileges.htm#TTSQL338